# I get this error "creating child process failed. Lof ID is 0002" when trying to install Abaqus on Linux PC (RedHat and Ubuntu)

Tags: linux

I tried to install Abaqus on my Linux PC but I get this error `creating child process failed. Log ID is 0002` when trying to install Abaqus license.

and when clicking on the technical report of this message I get the following

Technical details:

```
/opt/Abaqus/2/SIMULIA_Abaqus_CAE/Linux64/1/inst/common/installationFiles/code/unzip -qo "/opt/Abaqus/2/SIMULIA_Abaqus_CAE/Linux64/1/inst/common/installationFiles/code/siteIDandDslsStat.zip" -d "/tmp/InstallData-2020_03_19-135345-0700/log/CODE/linux_a64/SIMULIA_Abaqus_CAE.media-2020_03_19-135345-0700/tmp"
Stdout: 
Stderr: unzip: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
Action LaunchAppAction from feature CODE\linux_a64\SIMCAE_TP.prd failed.
Action ID: unzip_siteIDandDslsStat
Private ID: e77a37acd491df89c69f54482fd6abd92906543d74195410aa477e42014b88c9

Error code: Type: ERROR, Error: f5, Owner: 30a
```

It looks like it was trying to unzip the file `siteIDandDslsStat.zip` into `/tmp/InstallData-2020_03_19-135345-0700/log/CODE/linux_a64/SIMULIA_Abaqus_CAE.media-2020_03_19-135345-0700/tmp`

but failed. I though I should do `chmod -R 777 /tmp/*` first to give write permission but didn't work.

Note: I get same error when trying to install Abaqus on RedHat and Ubuntu.

Any help is appreciated. Now because of COVID-19 situation, I have to install Abaqus on my Ubuntu machine and work from home.

Comment: Please edit question, to show what you did to get the error.

Comment: I just started Abaqus installation and then proceed like any GUI installation and when get to the License I selected Flexnet and entered the server license and clicked next then I got this error.

Comment: You say that like you expect that we have done it a thousand times before, and know what you did. We don't I have never run this installer. I have no proprietary software on my machine.

Comment: It looks like something went wrong, and the program just spilt its guts. This error message is not meant for the user. It says, that there is a bug in the program, and the program was written in C, and some other stuff that I don't care about. You can ether become an un-payed debugger of the program, or tell the developers to sort there game out. Also you should never have to set permissions to 777: why would others need access. The program is running as you. And that chmod, does not give access to the sub-directory that is being written to.